# Spark read failed due to duplicate column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to read parquet file from S3 in databricks, using scala.
below is the simple read code

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(s"/mnt/$MountName/tstamp=2020_03_25")
display(df)
```

MountName is the dbfs where data is mounted from S3.
But I am getting error which is due to duplicate key in file.

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 813.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 813.0 (TID 79285, 10.179.245.218, executor 0): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/mnt/Alibaba_data/tstamp=2020_03_25/ts-1585154320710.parquet.gz. 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found duplicate field(s) "subtype": [subtype, subType] in case-insensitive mode
```

Now i need to overcome it. May be making the read case sensitive or by dropping the column while read, or by any other means if suggested.

Suggestion please.

Answer (score 4):

Try with case sensitivity enabled. 
`spark.sql.caseSensitive` should be set to `true`.